# BigQueryInsertJobOperator Configuration for default project ID

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow, airflow-2.x

I have a situation where my data lies in a different GCP project say "data-pro" and my compute project is set up as a different GCP project, which has access to "data-pro" 's tables.
So is there way to specify the default project-id using which the queries must run ?
i can see that there is a default data set , parameter .. but no default projectID.

SO my queries are as follows :

> select name ,id from employeedDB.employee .// this employeedDB is in data-proc

and my BigQueryInsertJobOperator Configuration is as below :

> BigQueryInsertJobOperator(dag=dag, task_id=name,
> gcp_conn_id=connection_id,--//connection_id over compute-proc
> configuration={
> "query": {
> "query": "{% include '"+sqlFile+"' %}",
> "useLegacySql": False
> },
> },
> pool='bqJobPool')

Comment: I'm facing the same kind of problem. I want that any query executed search in a particular project whatever where I run the project from AND when I don't specify a project ID in the FROM block of the query. It is somehow similar to the defaultDataset block proposed here (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query#queryrequest) but  only applied to the projectID. I don't think BigQuery is proposing this feature :/ . I think it can be a good use case for datalake environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the SQL statement can be changed to:

```
select name ,id from `<project_id>:employeedDB.employee`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define different connection id with different project (and you can set it either via parameter in each task or via "default_args" feature.